# Deduplication based on line prefixes in vim

Tags: vim, macros

I have a file created by find, like this...

```
./a/b/c/d/f.x
./a/b/c/e/shao.tnh
./a/b/c/e/ehn.he
./a/b/f/g/h
./a/b/u
```

I need to browse through it, but it's extremely large.

Is there any way to, say, have my cursor on the c in line 1, then have some sort of macro scan from cursor to beginning of line, output that scanned section to some log file, then go down a line and delete that line if it matches the scanned prefix pattern, ie ^./a/b/c, then repeat the process until it gets to a line that doesn't match?

In other words, I would press one key, to, in this case, delete the first three lines of the file, and possibly append the line "./a/b/c/" to a seperate logfile.

Ideally, I'd also have a macro that skips to the next line that doesn't have the prefix without modifying anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do *sounds* relatively easy with search-based ranges but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve. Could you add a simplified before/after example to your question?

Comment: i really don't know how to explain it eloquently, but i've actually already made some progress on a solution. are you on IRC, or do you care to join me on SO chat?

Answer (score 0):

```
:nnoremap <leader>dd mzv0"zy?\V\^<C-R>z<CR>V'zj"_D`zj:nohlsearch<CR>
```

If no weird characters appear (specifically, backslashes), this should prefix-deduplicate your line, and leave your prefix in `z` register; you can extend the mapping to switch to another buffer and paste it, or to shell-cat it to a file, or whatever you want. It overwrites the `z` mark and `z` register.

```
:nnoremap <leader>ds v0"zy?\V\^<C-R>z<CR>j:nohlsearch<CR>
```

This should get you to the first line not starting with the prefix. Overwrites `z` register, doesn't mess with marks.

**EDIT** for explanation:

```
mz     - set the mark `z` (on the character `c`)
v      - start character-wise visual mode
0      - jump to start of the line
"zy    - yank the visual contents (`./a/b/c`) into the `z` register
?      - start backwards search
\V     - enable very no magic mode (`:help /magic` - basically, only backslash is
         special)
\^     - start of line in very no magic mode
<C-R>z - paste the contents of the `z` register (`./a/b/c`)
<CR>   - perform the search (we end up on the *last* mention of `./a/b/c` at the
         start of the line)
V      - start linewise visual mode
'z     - jump to the line where the `z` mark is (the line where we started)
j      - down one line
"_D    - cut the visual selection into the black hole register so we don't
         pollute more than necessary (we delete every line starting with
         `./a/b/c` except the first)
`z     - jump to the character where the `z` mark is (`c` in the first line)
:nohighlight<CR> - remove the search highlight
```

Analogously for the `\ds` mapping.

To prevent backslashes from messing up the search, you'd need to replace all the backslashes with double backslashes before performing search.

**EDIT2:** Yeah, this works even with backslashes:

```
:nnoremap <leader>dd mzv0"zy?\V\^<C-R>=escape(@z, '\\')<CR><CR>V'zj"_D`z:nohlsearch<CR>
```

Explanation of the added bits:

```
<C-R>= - starts the paste of result of expression evaluation
escape(@z, '\\') - escapes the backslashes in `z` register
<CR>   - ends the expression and pastes it in the search box
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? Also, what if some lines DO contain backslashes, and the only char that I can guarantee that it doesn't contain is a `NUL`? Would there be any way to modify this to accomodate such a situation? If, not, I should definitely be able to work around that, but if there was, it would be great.

Comment: Also, someone on IRC came up with this.. `/^\V\(\\=escape(@a, '/')\)\@!  \V` Is that at all useful?

Comment: do you think you could give some feedback on these?
    `:nnoremap n v0"ry/^\(<C-R>=escape(@r, '/')<CR>\v)@!<CR>$ 
:nnoremap y F/ 
:nnoremap d v0"ry:!echo '<C-R>=escape(@r, "'")<CR>' >> ~/logfile<CR><CR>d/^\(<C-R>=escape(@r, '/')<CR>\v)@!<CR>$
`